# Retrofit2 Android onResponse: null

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need single value from json. but shows its null
My json

```
 [
    {
        "cat_id": "23",
        "cat_name": "cat_name1"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "23",
        "cat_name": "cat_name2"
    },
```

Api

```
    @GET("categories.php")
    Call<List<CatModel>> getMovies();
```

Model

```
public class CatModel {

    @SerializedName("cat_id")
    @Expose
    private String catId;
    
    @SerializedName("cat_name")
    @Expose
    private String catName;
    


    public String getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(String catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

}
```

Code:

```
 private void loaddata(){
        Call<List<CatModel>> call = api.getMovies();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CatModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CatModel>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<CatModel>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().toString() );  ///Working fine
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().get(i).getCatName() ); ///onResponse: null
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CatModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

I need get single item from json only "cat_name" . response.body().get(i).getCatName() ); this one null.
get value using getter and setter not work . in volley its working fine .. how can we get it using retrofit

update: we already add okhttp

```
public class ServiceMain {
private static final String MAIN = "http://mydoman.com/ok/v2.1/";
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) throws Exception {

    OkHttpClient httpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MAIN)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient).build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);

}
```

}

Comment: How do you create retrofit instance?

Comment: try {
            api = ServiceMain.createService(CatApi.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().toString() ); working fine

Comment: Because you get json. Json from internet is string. But your retrofitService make convert to model with Gson for example?

Comment: I add answer how to set converter, if you don't set it.

Comment: CatModel  serverData = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), CatModel.class);

Comment: serverData.getCatName()  // error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: Are you convert array json to object?

Comment: You need List<CatModel> cats = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), new TypeToken<List<CatModel>>(){}.getType());. But if you add GsonConverter it is not necessary

Comment: cats.get(1).getCatName() //Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Answer (score 1):

Do you set retrofit sevice as next?:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

For GsonConverterFactory need add dependency in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

May be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call response.body().toString()  twice, it will give you NPE.

```
  if(response.isSuccessful()){
```

// use GSON/ moshi/ Jackson, to load the response(response.body) in model class.
// then use the model class for your other operation.

```
 }
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main and IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

Comment: based on your response you either store it into model or in string variable. don't ask your list based operation issues here.

Comment: CatModel  serverData = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(response), CatModel.class);

Comment: serverData.getCatName() // error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: have you skipped gson parsing lessons, you need gson to convert your json array response before converting it to model. Read how to parse. And  to your original question, don't call reponse.body twice.

Comment: if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    String result = response.body().toString();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    CatModel pojo = gson.fromJson(result, CatModel.class);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+pojo.getCatName() );

                }

Comment: you response is in jsonArray, not json object, so  Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Model>>(){}.getType();
List<Model> posts = gson.fromJson(response.body(), listType);

Comment: posts.get(0).getCatName() // error java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to c.c.c.j

Answer (score 0):

Try it please, may be it will work for you:

```
private void loaddata(){
        Call<List<CatModel>> call = api.getMovies();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CatModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CatModel>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<CatModel>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<CatModel> catList = response.body();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + catList.toString());  ///Working fine
                    for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + catList.get(i).getCatName() ); ///onResponse: null
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Response Error " + String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CatModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Response Error " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: look like you code 100% correct but it gave onResponse: null...

Answer (score 0):

Ouh my. I don't see at once. You need remove modifier private. Gson don't work with that modifier. Gson work with public or package visibility. Try this model:

```
public class CatModel {

    @SerializedName("cat_id")
    @Expose
    public String catId;
    
    @SerializedName("cat_name")
    @Expose
    public String catName;
    


    public String getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(String catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

}
```

Comment: although there is reflection, it must work with private field.

Comment: public also same problem getter not work .. i used this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/